# How to launch the browser on client side using selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am new to selenium. I am developed one application using a selenium web driver for doing some actions on the webpage. It's perfectly working when I am running locally i.e., it launches a browser in my machine. I deployed this application on a VM server so the script runs on the server(launched browser in VM Ware Machine), not on the client-side. Can anyone help me with how can I launch the browser on the client-side?

Comment: If you want browser to open for your client's, you will have to make it as an Console / WPF app or something similar.

Comment: Can you please give the same snippet code. That will help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You could just use `NUnit`, too.  You wouldn't need a console then.

Comment: I am using Java for the application. NUnit supports Java...?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to create Hub and Nodes using selenium grid

You can refer this link to see step by step

http://www.seleniumeasy.com/selenium-tutorials/how-to-configure-selenium-grid

Your server will be hub and your client machine will be node

Answer (score 2):

If you trigger from one machine, you can launch a browser on another machine using the selenium-grid concept
But both machines are under the same LAN.

Here you want to execute on the client machine. It is not possible, because your machine and client machine won't be under the same network

Comment: Partially agree.

Comment: My point is if we consider some banking applications it launches new windows in client machine performing all actions. Then it is all also possible..!

Comment: * new browser window

Comment: You can handle new window as well, by using of window handles